# Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin Image preprocessing Error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, sentinel-2, plugins

I'm using QGIS 3.10 for MacOS with Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin 6.4.7

Currently, I'm trying to perform initial image pre-processing of one of the Sentinel-2 images.

[image]

However, when I click Run I got the following error

[image]

Has anybody encountered such or similar problem?

Unfortunately, Google didn't help me this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the same issue has been already discussed and resolved [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366848/scp-plugin-for-qgis-3-10-on-mac).