# Cannot run semi-automatic classification (SCP) on Mac

Tags: qgis, python, mac

When I click the run button, a window appear with an Open Option. When I select it, the QGIS Software reopens over the one that's already open.

There's this message:

```
2020-12-17T13:47:15     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/rodrigocarvalho/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/maininterface/landsatTab.py", line 640, in performLandsatCorrection
      self.landsat(cfg.ui.label_26.text(), o)
      File "/Users/rodrigocarvalho/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/maininterface/landsatTab.py", line 331, in landsat
      LDNmList = cfg.utls.findDNmin(tPMDN, NoData)
      File "/Users/rodrigocarvalho/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/core/utils.py", line 2006, in findDNmin
      o = cfg.utls.multiProcessRaster(rasterPath = inputRaster, functionBand = 'No', functionRaster = cfg.utls.rasterUniqueValuesWithSum, nodataValue = noDataVal, progressMessage = cfg.QtWidgetsSCP.QApplication.translate('semiautomaticclassificationplugin', 'DOS1 calculation'), deleteArray = 'No', parallel = cfg.parallelArray)
      File "/Users/rodrigocarvalho/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/core/utils.py", line 4675, in multiProcessRaster
      manager = cfg.MultiManagerSCP()
      File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py", line 56, in Manager
      m.start()
      File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 547, in start
      self._address = reader.recv()
      File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 250, in recv
      buf = self._recv_bytes()
      File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 407, in _recv_bytes
      buf = self._recv(4)
      File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 383, in _recv
      raise EOFError
     EOFError
```

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I didn't see any solution for mac, and I ran into some other situation as well, such as multiprocessing issue. According to [Peter](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/40472?fbclid=IwAR3jjBEBa07QY8NyvqDDmrST1lXpcQN0t6gJqQwh_XzBaOWSuiLAUtnrnWk#issuecomment-739802494)'s comment on Github, 3.10 will soon out of support. I am running 3.16.1 currently, and multiprocessing errors crashed the SCP too. I ran some multiprocessing related test codes inside the qgis console, the whole software crashed and restarted; thus, I assumed it's the issue of the software itself :/.

Answer (score 0):

I got SCP to work by installing downgraded SCP v6 instead of 7. Used QGIS 3.10, and had both GDAL 2.4 and 3.1 installed. Ran Python to install/import NumPy, Matplotlib separately in Terminal.

Also, I'm running all this on Big Sur 11.1. Works flawlessly.

Comment: Which version of QGIS 3.10 are you using @sys123?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem. I have tried https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/370665/158608
Rachel has given an option here..
Go to Settings > Options > System > Environment Enable Use Custom Variables (check mark in the box)

First select Prepend, under variable enter PATH, under value enter (***Make sure you update the pathname with the version you downloaded. In this example, this was python 3.8 but yours may be different depending on when you download this.)

/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:

it has worked for some people but not me..

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/229746)