# "IndexError: list index out of range" for SCP plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error, landsat-8, scp

I am using QGIS 3.20 on a Mac with the SCP plugin for pre-processing Landsat 8 OLI images. While I pre-process, I check the following options:

1. Allow calculation of brightness temperature in Celsius.
2. Apply DOS1 correction.
3. Perform PAN sharpening.

I am getting the following warning, and after that the processing stops at 5%. Apparently it might be happening for MacOS only, because the same thing runs smoothly on a Linux Virtual Machine (no I am not comfortable with the step of performing the steps on the Virtual machine and reverting back to the main OS, as the VM is pretty slow on a Mac Host).

The warning:

> File "/Users/xxxx/Library/Application
> Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/maininterface/landsatTab.py",
> line 641, in performLandsatCorrection
> self.landsat(cfg.ui.label_26.text(), o)
> File "/Users/xxxx/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/maininterface/landsatTab.py",
> line 398, in landsat
> argumentList = panList[1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366848/scp-plugin-for-qgis-3-10-on-mac?fbclid=IwAR0IYxci5lGnju3383y7eDrIGMXF20A42g1If0o4hsbpWmLgVZo9j01BTpI).replace('LDNm', str(LDNmList[0]))
> IndexError: list index out of range

I have set the SCP plugin to use the Anaconda installation for GDAL and Python based computations.

I have tried this link [QGIS / SCP / GDAL Configuration](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366848/scp-plugin-for-qgis-3-10-on-mac?fbclid=IwAR0IYxci5lGnju3383y7eDrIGMXF20A42g1If0o4hsbpWmLgVZo9j01BTpI), but it does not work as well. The same error happens.